# PHP return reference to array in other class

Tags: php, arrays

I have a class that contains the following:

```
class TestClass {
    protected $items = [];

    public function toArray(){
        return $this->items;
    }

    // Items gets set using set(array $items){}
}
```

In another class I call this:

```
$tmpList = $list->toArray();
```

Now if I am not mistaken, this will create a whole new separate array, so if the array in `TestClass` has 100k items calling `toArray()` will create another array consisting of another 100k items for two arrays totaling 200k items.

Is there a way for me to just return a reference to the items in `TestClass` so I have one array with 100k items and `$tmpList` just references those items?

If I do this to sort the array, the array doesn't change

```
$tmpList = $list->toArray();
usort($tmpList, function($a, $b) use ($orderBy, $direction){
    if($direction == 'desc'){
        return $b->$orderBy > $a->$orderBy;
    }elseif($direction == 'asc'){
        return $b->$orderBy < $a->$orderBy;
    }
});
```

If I append this after it:

```
$list->set($tmpList);
```

The array gets sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$tmpList = &$list->toArray();
```

Even though you should test the real performance impact as PHP acts unexpected with using references.

**Update:** Actualy it seems you also have to add the & infront of the function declaration. Got this part wrong.

```
public function &toArray(){ ... }
```

Comment: That *means* something very different in PHP than "memory optimisation". **Do not use this unless you mean to allow two separate scopes to _manipulate_ the same value.**

Comment: I made a function `protected function &arrayRef(){return $this->items;}` that does basically the same thing but returns it as a reference and used your assignment method.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Don't complain to me when you get unexpected side effects yet see no real difference in memory consumption...

Comment: @deceze Unexpected low performance, yes. Have been there. That you have to be careful as always when using references, granted. But unexpected side effects? Never expierienced those. Anything perticular?

Comment: @Torge When returning an array from a function you usually expect there to be no reference. This can easily lead to code manipulating the array outside the class and unexpectedly changing the array inside the class. Side effect. The sorting should simply be done inside the class.

Comment: I guess that is why an & is needed on both sides. If you don't specify & as the caller you will not get a reference. I don't see any "unexpected" side effects there. But as I said. Ofc you have to be always carefull when handling references.

Answer (score 4):

No, it will not duplicate the entire array's contents. Items in the array will be handled by reference. PHP will optimise this behind the scenes. PHP is not C. It has no references in the same sense that C does (pointers to memory locations). You do not need to worry about optimising this.

Comment: Not Sur. From http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php we have "Array assignment always involves value copying. Use the reference operator to copy an array by reference."

Comment: @Luc *Logically.* That's not about memory-management.

Comment: @deceze I don't think that this is true... I have a function that will order an array, if I call the `toArray()`, then `usort` on the array, it doesn't get sorted. However, if I do the same thing, then replace the original array it does get sorted.

Comment: Object references within an array are copied along with the array. Any change to the order of the array does not affect the original array. Changes in any object within the array will be reflected in the original array. However, any changes to a reference in the array copy will not be reflected in the original array.

Comment: I made a function `protected function &arrayRef(){return $this->items;}` I then call it like this: `$tmpList = &$list->arrayRef();` I then don't have to save it back to the array like I had to without using `&`.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn If you want a reference that, when manipulated also manipulated the origin, then use my aproach putting an & in the command.
But if you are "only" concerned about performace and data duplication, then deceze is right. Data gets duplicated only on demand which can be often quicker than the very slow reference implementation of PHP.